# Only want clang for source-to-source transforms; how do I build clang without the LLVM backend?

Tags: clang, llvm

I am using clang to write source-to-source transforms, so I do not need the code generation backend.  Further, the size of the Clang/LLVM executable is a problem:

- I am constantly recompiling my transforms and the linking stage takes a long time.
- If I ever have to run it in the debugger, it takes minutes to load into gdb.

How do I configure the Clang/LLVM build process to build Clang without the LLVM backend?

Comment: I don't think LLVM is really an optional extra for Clang. More than two thirds of the clang .cpp files include LLVM header files, so even if someone once intended any part of Clang to work without LLVM, most people who've worked on Clang seem to have disregarded that possibility.